# Generating pairs of pseudorandom numbers

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, computer-science

I'm looking for a method that generates pairs of pseudorandom numbers with the following conditions:

- Every pair from $(1, 1)$ to $(n, m)$ is seen exactly once before repeating, for any choice of integers $n$ and $m$. It's fine if some pairs are more than $(n, m)$, as these can be skipped, but ideally not too many (so something like rounding $n$ and $m$ up to the next power of 2 is fine).
- The method can be seeded with different inputs to produce different orders.
- Small space complexity, ideally $O(1)$.

I'm using this to generate bipartite graphs with a given number of vertices on each side ($n$ and $m$) and a given number of edges (the first $k$ pairs generated).

I've looked at linear congruence generators and the [PCRG](https://www.pcg-random.org/index.html) method looks promising, but I'm not sure how either of these could be adapted for these requirements.

Does anyone know of a method that achieves this? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It is your non-repeating requirement that is the biggest problem. That is very much non-random, since later outputs clearly depend in previous ones, so no standard PRNG will do that. Instead, you will have to do that yourself, either by skipping repeats, or by treating it as if you are pulling cards at random from a deck of $n*m$ cards, choosing randomly only from the remaining ones. Unfortunately, that takes space.

Comment: Note that the 2-dimensional aspect is no problem. It is equivalent to choosing $k$ numbers from $\{1,2,...,mn\}$. Each number maps uniquely to a pair using $i\rightarrow (1+(i-1)\%n,1+\lfloor (i-1)/n \rfloor)$.

Comment: If time complexity is unimportant (relative to space), you can also do what is described [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/129757), looping over all items, and choosing whether to include it or not with the correct probability.

Comment: *"I'm using this to generate bipartite graphs"*. So the generator only needs to generate a finite number of pairs. That's simpler than an infinite generator. You just want (partial) permutations of the numbers in [1, nm]. Typically, how big is nm?

Comment: You can do this for huge nm with small space requirements using [Format-preserving encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption). I have an example in Python:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51429458/4014959

Comment: Here's a demo that generates pair permutations, using Blake2s hashing: https://gist.github.com/PM2Ring/099335b52fdf1fb4d0a2e17952478de5

Comment: Using separate generators for n and m would impose repetition of every $n_i$ m times so to pair with all $m_k$. Thus the simplest is IMO the suggestion of Jaap Scherphuis with a LCG of period mn.